# Keeping FTP control connection alive

Tags: multithreading, ftp, controls

A while back I asked a question regarding keeping the control connection on an FTP session alive during a large transfer.  Although I though I had success after [implementing a solution for a question I'd already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269012/using-threading-to-keep-ftp-control-port-alive), it appears as though the ISP is the problem, i.e. they are causing my control connections to die during large transfers.

Interestingly, the old-school FTP client program "Leap-FTP" gets around this issue by just sending 'NOOP' commands to the server on the control connection during a download.  While other popular clients die during transfers (Filezilla, my Python FTP script), LeapFTP runs strong due to this workaround.

I've done some research into threading and Queue, but am having trouble coming up with the code to make this happen.

The solution seems simple enough (in my head, at least): initiate a download, while that download function runs, send a NOOP command every n seconds.  Stop sending the NOOP command after the download function completes.

I'm hoping that someone can give me a suggestion as to how this might be done.  Will it involve the use of threading, Queue, or is there a more simple solution?

Bottom line is, after a lot of testing, the 'NOOP' command is going to have to be sent during the large downloads (which take place on high-numbered TCP ports).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on a Unix, it would be just as efficient to have the control connection program open the sockets for a transfer and then spawn a new process to do the transfer. That would leave the control program ready to wait for completion, send NOOP commands, or even start new transfers if the FTP server can support it.

That is sort of how the original FTP model was supposed to work and the reason it uses a control connection and separate data connections instead of the HTTP model with control and data mixed together.

Answer (score 1):

In order to handle multiple sockets at one time in a single program, you can use the `select` function instead of threads. This is either simpler or more complicated, depending on your programming experience.

I find threads are usually simple but when something does go wrong debugging it is a real pain, while writing the code for socket multiplexing using `select` is more complex but less difficult to debug than threads.

The basics of using `select` is that you set up your sockets and call the `select` function. It will tell you which sockets are ready to read or write. Then you check the time. If it's been X seconds since your last NOOP, send one on the control socket. If the transfer socket is ready to read or write, handle it. If the control socket is ready to read, read it and check for NOOP response, error messages, control channel being closed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care (much, anyway) about performance in this case, it's probably easiest to use a separate thread for it that sits in a loop simply sleeps for N seconds, checks to see if it's been cancelled, and if not sends a NOP and sleeps again.